# IndexedDB and same origin policy

Tags: indexeddb

The following is taken from Mozilla's web site:

> Like most web storage solutions, IndexedDB follows a same-origin policy. So while you can access stored data within a domain, you cannot access data across different domains.

I understand the same-origin policy when it comes to accessing different domains from Javascript. But I don't understand how that applies to IndexedDB. I thought IndexedDB was just a database and you store whatever you want in it. How does an IndexedDB know anything about a domain and why would it even care if it did know? Even if I manage to retrieve data from different domains (which is possible), I can still store that data in the database. So what does the domain have to do with this?

I'm building a single page web app that runs in Electron and can access data from multiple domains. I will store this data in an IndexedDB database. Presumably I will only have one database. It just isn't clear what, if anything, the same-origin policy would have in this context.

If my web app doesn't navigate to a url but only retrieves data from a backend service using XMLHttpRequest, then technically there is no domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SOP in this case refers to the origin of the script which is doing the accessing of IndexedDB. A script from example.com/foo.js can access the IndexedDB for example.com, but a script from evil.com/bar.js cannot access it. More to the point, there's a different instance of IndexedDB, local storage, session storage etc. for each domain you visit.

Also, it's not about not being able to write data from evil.com to the database for example.com. It's about a script from evil.com *accessing* the database from example.com. So the browser doesn't tag data with it's origin, but rather scripts. Which makes sense, because it's malicious scripts which are the problem, rather than the data itself.

Comment: But if my script is embedded in the web app as javascript files, there is no domain associated with that script. So how does IndexedDB deal with that?

Comment: I don't know what electron uses as the domain for scripts embedded in the app. Might be localhost or something specific to it. In any case, if you also load a script from a real domain in your app, and if Electron honours the SOP, then that script won't be able to access the app's data.

Comment: Electron uses localhost. Electron honors SOP but this can be disabled. Since I need to access data from different domains, I will be required to disable this, so in that case I believe SOP has no affect on IndexedDB databases.